# How to divide jquery tab to 4 equal divs?

Tags: jquery, html, google-visualization, jquery-tabs

I'm using jquery tabs, and in one of my tabs  have 4 google charts (each contained by a div).
I want to positions each div on 1/4 of the tab area. (in north, south, east and west of the screan).

Right now my html is :

```
<div id="chartsTab">
<!--Div that will hold the volume column chart-->
<div id="chart_div_volume" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
</div>
<div id="chart_div_midp" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="chart_div_spread" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="chart_div_volatility" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
</div>
```

So my charts are one beneath the other.

Comment: give them an appropriate width/height and float left.

Comment: Might want to look at the float css property

Comment: can you be more specific, i'm quite a novice in css

Comment: which one should have float left or right ?

Comment: @omerbach Have you solved your problem? Are you getting any other problem related to the answers you got?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle showing an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/2wePu/).

HTML:

```
<div id="chartsTab">
    <!--Div that will hold the volume column chart-->
    <div id="chart_div_volume" class="tab" ></div>
    <div id="chart_div_midp" class="tab"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div id="chart_div_spread" class="tab"></div>
    <div id="chart_div_volatility" class="tab"></div>
</div>
```

*Note the use of the div with `clear:both` at the place where you want to force a new row.*

Just adjust the width to the one you want. If you want it to take full screen well consider using %. But note that % may get to a wrongful size if the browser is re-sized. So if you use % consider adding a `min-width`.

CSS:

```
.tab {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 3000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the charts a width of 50% and float left.

html:

```
<div id="chartsTab">
    <!--Div that will hold the volume column chart-->
    <div id="chart_div_volume" class="tab" >1</div>
    <div id="chart_div_midp" class="tab">2</div>
    <div id="chart_div_spread" class="tab">3</div>
    <div id="chart_div_volatility" class="tab">4</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#chartsTab {
    width: 200px;
}
.tab {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}

.tab:nth-child(1){
 background-color: #f00;   
}

.tab:nth-child(2){
 background-color: #0f0;   
}

.tab:nth-child(4){
 background-color: #00f;   
}

.tab:nth-child(5){
 background-color: #000;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wePu/2/